# Literal stack error with jurabib

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

I am receiving the following error:

```
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry Orth
while executing---line 3023 of file jurabib.bst
1 is an integer literal, not a function, for entry Orth
while executing---line 3023 of file jurabib.bst
```

The MWE that produces it, looks like:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[titleformat=all,howcited=normal]{jurabib}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@Book{Orth,
  author     = {Elsbet Orth},
  title      = {Die Fehden der Reichsstadt Frankfurt am Main im Sp\"atmittelalter: Fehderecht und Fehdepraxis im 14. und 15.\,Jahrhundert},
  shorttitle = {Die Fehden der Reichsstadt Frankfurt am Main},
  date       = {1973},
  series     = {Frankfurter historische Abhandlungen, Band~6},
  address    = {Wiesbaden},
  howcited   = {1},
  school     = {Frankfurt am Main},
  type       = {Dissertation},
  dissyear   = {1971}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Orth}.

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas? I am using the latest jurabib in MikTeX and never had any trouble with the stack in BibTeX before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `biblatex` `jurabib` does not know a `date` field, it only knows `year`. If I change from `date` to `year` things work just fine.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[titleformat=all,howcited=normal]{jurabib}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@book{Orth,
  author     = {Elsbet Orth},
  title      = {Die Fehden der Reichsstadt Frankfurt am Main im Sp\"atmittelalter: Fehderecht und Fehdepraxis im 14. und 15.\,Jahrhundert},
  shorttitle = {Die Fehden der Reichsstadt Frankfurt am Main},
  year       = {1973},
  series     = {Frankfurter historische Abhandlungen},
  number     = {6},
  address    = {Wiesbaden},
  howcited   = {1},
  school     = {Frankfurt am Main},
  type       = {Dissertation},
  dissyear   = {1971}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Orth}.

\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\bibliography{literatur}
\end{document}
```

[image: Orth, Elsbet: Die Fehden der Reichsstadt Frankfurt am Main im Spätmittelalter: Fehderecht und Fehdepraxis im 14. und 15.Jahrhundert. Wiesbaden, 1973 (zugl. Dissertation, Frankfurt am Main, 1971), Frankfurter historische Abhandlungen 6 (zitiert: Orth Die Fehden der Reichsstadt Frankfurt am Main)]

Comment: Thanks @moewe, seems I was too blind, as this was the initial reason I was modifying this entry. Fixed the problem also in the large document with the entry.

Comment: @TobiBS It is a bit unfortunate that the error message is not more informative. But I guess since `year` is a required field the developer did not put much effort into catching the error earlier and giving a more useful error message.

Comment: Well even more unfortunate, that in other circumstances the `date` instead of `year` is not creating any visible issues (other than omitting a year in the printout): `@Book{Orth,
  author     = {Elsbet Orth},
  title      = {Die Fehden der Reichsstadt Frankfurt am Main im Sp\"atmittelalter: Fehderecht und Fehdepraxis im 14. und 15.\,Jahrhundert},
  date       = {1973},
  series     = {Frankfurter historische Abhandlungen},
  address    = {Wiesbaden},
  howcited   = {1},
  shorttitle = {Die Fehden der Reichsstadt Frankfurt am Main},
}`